# Power supply enclosure

Tags: power

I have bought [enclosure for my power supply](http://www.tme.eu/en/details/abs-48/power-supplies-enclosures/) ([datasheet](http://www.tme.eu/en/Document/aaa714c4aa6e2cabc8d2c28c1fecd29f/abs-48.pdf)), which looks like the follow:

[image]

How can i connect the plugs to my circiut? Soldering is not an option because the box is made from ABS.

Comment: I suspect that the intent is that you solder some spring contacts to your PCB that connect with the pins when the PCB is assembled into the box. Does the documentation not offer any clues?

Comment: Is there a butt splice cable shoe made for it? Please note that it must lock in place firmly (>2 N) or it will not pass UL/CE.

Comment: @winny: A box this size is not intended to hold a >400W power supply!

Comment: Please post the link to the enclosure's datasheet.  It's not inconceivable that some hints about the connection technique are mentioned there.

Comment: http://www.tme.eu/en/Document/aaa714c4aa6e2cabc8d2c28c1fecd29f/abs-48.pdf link to the datasheet. I did not found any useful information about the wiring.. (Link to the product: http://www.tme.eu/en/details/abs-48/power-supplies-enclosures/)

Comment: @DavidTweed Sorry, wrong button. Newton, not Ampere. But you are correct, this is made for spring contacts, not crimp plugs.

Comment: Great! Thank for the answers! I have never heard about spring contacts so far... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the pins are 4mm in diameter, so if the manufacturer does not offer a matching contact, you could conceivably pull the center contact out of an [RCA jack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RCA_connector) (3.175 mm), spread it out a bit, and solder it to your PCB in the appropriate orientation.